# Deploy django app on heroku has error: DisallowedHost at / Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'ecommerceyy.herokuapp.com'

Tags: django, heroku

When I want to deploy my Django App on Heroku, I met an error as below:

`DisallowedHost at /
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'ecommerceyy.herokuapp.com'. You may need to add 'ecommerceyy.herokuapp.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.`

However, I have code in production.py like:

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.herokuapp.com']
```

And my wsgi.py is like:

```
import os 

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ecommerce.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And encrypt ssl/tls https like:

```
CORS_REPLACE_HTTPS_REFERER      = True
HOST_SCHEME                     = "https://"
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER         = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT             = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE           = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE              = True
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS  = True
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS             = 1000000
SECURE_FRAME_DENY               = True
```

I modify my setting.py into a settings folder

[image]

the BASE_DIR is like `os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))`

In the **init**.py in the settings folder, the code is like from

```
from .base import *
from .production import *

try:
    from .local import *
except:
    pass
```

So what's wrong with my app?

Comment: Where do you tell Django to use the `production` settings module? Your code only contains a reference to `ecommerce.settings`.

Comment: I modify my setting.py into a settings folder and the BASE_DIR is like os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))). In the __init__.py in the settings folder, the code is like from .base import *
from .production import *

try:
    from .local import *
except:
    pass

Comment: Do you override it in `settings.local`? Can you confirm that your production settings are being loaded properly and that `ALLOWED_HOSTS` actually has that value?

Comment: Have you tried this: `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*.herokuapp.com']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commit out from .base & from .local, only push .production to heroku, it works.

Answer (score 3):

Heroku has added the django_heroku package which handles this along with several other nice pieces of functionality.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

What you can do:

- Open `settings.py`.
- On top add: `import django_heroku`.
- Add: `django_heroku.settings(locals())`.

Then push code with all `requirements.txt`, `procfiles` and `runtime.txt`.